# Epson L3110 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: printing, epson

Are there any drivers available for this printer? Thank you.

I first downloaded the generic driver from https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule. Went on terminal and did the command stated on the site. When I tried to install it my ubuntu software store popped up and gave me an error message of "Failed to install file: not supported. [Screenshot of my error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doy02.png) I ran the

```
apt-get install lsb
```

as stated on the website.

`epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb` is the file I downloaded.

Comment: Which file did you download?What is the name of the file? Which command did you run? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: `epson-printer-utility` is not a driver, but an utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find drivers at the official site.

https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Download the `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.7.7-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb` and copy it to your Home user directory.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install ./epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.7.7-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```

to install.

Then add a new printer in Settings.

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Comment: I keep getting an error message. Failed to install file: not supported

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what file do you download, what are you doing next and what error do you get.

Comment: The correct file is `amd64` `deb`.

Comment: yes that it what I downloaded. Still got the error message

Comment: I'll update the answer with some more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am actually "new" to ubuntu again. Haven't used ubuntu for years now, getting tired of windows so I wanted to get back in to Ubuntu.

Comment: Finally, u are a life saver boss. Thank you so much. Much love from the Philippines.

Comment: this shit is buggy as hell. after installing package from epson site ubuntu still tries to download it itself

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old thread and now Ubuntu is reached up to 22.04. Still the same issue there with EPSON drivers availability. No clear answer on how to install and what to install on EPSON site.
After several trial and errors this is what worked for me. Hope that will help some one else as well.

I have EPSON L3110 printer and the local OS is Ubuntu 22.04:

1. Remove your current printer from the settings.
2. Download driver file i.e. deb from : https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/printer-driver-escpr_1.6.17-2_amd64.deb.html
3. To install it, run :

   sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.7.21-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
4. Add printer again

That's all!!!

> This driver works with several other EPSON printers as well, you need
> to give a try!

Comment: Why are you suggesting an old driver from 18.04 repo when new drivers are available at the official Epson site?

Comment: I have already tried those latest drivers, but somehow my printer was not able to recognise  those properly with 22.04 ubuntu. Hence tried this one and it worked smoothly.

Comment: The last step is important. I nearly threw away this answer because I missed the last step: 4. Add printer again